# conditional where clause when qty is greater than zero

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, where-clause

I have a field called Bin_ID with three different Bin ID's for items.

```
Bin_id = Red
Bin_id = Blue
Bin_id= Green
```

There is also a field called Unit_quantity

I want to add to my where clause the following logic: If Bin_ID green has a unit_qty Greater than zero then I want to remove it from my results.

How would I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not` and conditions in parentheses.

```
where not (Bin_ID = 'Green' and unit_qty > 0)
```